# Autoloading a bunch of small classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bunch of very small classes (say, different errors) in the Rails app (so all the goodies from `active_support` are available and I'm not afraid to use them) and  putting them in separate files seem to only increase clutter but I don't like to require the large file everywhere it is needed either. What are the best practices for dealing with this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let a particular file be loaded only when a particular module is accessed by using the `Kernel#autoload` method.

```
autoload(:Foo, "foo.rb")
autoload(:Bar, "bar.rb")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put the file in `config/initializers` so it is loaded on application startup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that still utilizes Rails autoloading

```
# app/models/foo/errors.rb
module Foo
  class A; end
  class B; end
end

# app/models/foo.rb
module Foo
  require 'foo/errors.rb'
end
```